# Procedure for complexity analysis from first principles

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

Say I wanted to perform complexity analysis from first principles on this simple loop -

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    a = i + 1;
}
```

Here is what I have done, is this the correct procedure or am I way off?

Initial assignment of 0 to i: 1 operation

Loop executed n times:

- Comparison of i to n: performed n+1 times
- Increment i: operation performed n times
- Assignment of i +1 to a: two operations performed n times

So total number of operations: 1 + (n+1) + n + 2n = 4n + 2
And this has Big Oh(n) complexity.

Is this correct? Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Yes it is correct, it also has Omega(n) complexity and Theta(n) complexity.

Comment: Yeah, next you'll learn which things you can ignore (like when adding polynomials, you only ever need the highest order term.) But thinking about all the operations is a great way to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The final conclusion is correct**, the algorithm is `O(n)`

However, when analyzing algorithms we usually avoid counting *exactly* how many ops are done, and look only for upper and lower bounds, since **the exact details might be implementation dependent**.

For example, in your code - [loop-unrolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding) might decrease the number of compare ops in the code, and the exact number of ops you calculated is no exactly the number of ops done in practice.

Also, this assumes `a` is an `int` or some primitive type, and the `operator=`, `operator+` are done in constant time. If `a` is for example some kind of big-integer, or string like, and you overloaded the operators - maybe each `operator=` is `O(|a|)`, which makes the algorithm `O(nlogn)`, or `O(n^2)`, (or something else), depending on the specific implementation of the type of `a`.

Answer (score 1):

It is completely correct. (But be careful that each operation should take O(1) time. If for example an operation is a function call, you must also consider its run-time complexity)

Next time, you might find a "critical" operation and count only the number of times that operation executes. For example, in your example, it is obvious that there will be a constant number of times comparison and increment operations for each assignment operation executed, so you would be fine if you only counted the number of assignments.

It is always easy when you directly count the number of executions of operations. More difficult cases arise when you cannot directly count but for example arrive at a recursive formula, i.e. T(n+1) = a T(n/b) + f(n) etc.